# Is it possible to register user via firebase auth with just sms service and offline, i.e WITHOUT INTERNET

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I know to register firebase user via email and phone auth using internet

Is it possible to create or register with just an sms service and register user to firebase

PS:I have checked of Twillio and Angular Js

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

Comment: No unfortunately there's no way firebase interaction requires internet for user to communicate with auth server even if you're trying to do OTP authentication then also you'll need internet

Answer (score 1):

As Mr. Patel, mentioned in his comment, in order to create an user account either with user and password or via sms, you need to be connected to the internet. There is no way you can register a user to Firebase without internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible directly to do this, but i can suggest you some trick to do the same.

You can create an simple dummy app in android in your phone and trigger a brodcast reciever on recieved sms, define some initial keywords in sms that user will type in message then in your mobile app the code will trigger each time you will recieve an sms.

You can create and api endpoint using firebase cloud functions and in your mobile app on recieving the sms read the messgae and split according to pattern like

> REG someone@example.com

and send the email and phone number of user to api using volley or async task
then you can create users in firebase auth directly with node Admin SDK

Alternatively you can buy some service online (twilio) i think they have some triggers on sms recieve and do the same on server

Hope this solves you query